Transformers.js extension is redownloading the model again and again after closing the extension tab
I am trying to build a chrome extension using transformers.js library in order to test its limits and see if onDevice ML can be a choice in some cases.
Based on the example provided in their official repo i am adding new features.
As i added the translation pipeline i saw something strange, namely that the model was downloading again and again after each opening and closing of the browser.
class MyTranslationPipeline {
static task = "translation";
static model = "Xenova/nllb-200-distilled-600M";
static instance = null;

static async getInstance(progress_callback = null) {
    if (this.instance === null) {
        console.log("Loading translation pipeline...");
        this.instance = pipeline(this.task, this.model, {progress_callback});
    }

    return this.instance;
 }
}

The original example showcased env.allowLocalModels = false; but i set it back to true and it didn't work, i am expecting that when i reopen the browser the model is to be loaded from cache where it already is.
Cache entries
